Making div the same width as grandparent
I am working on a school project in react where the goal is to build a website which will display movies collected from a database. When a movie is clicked a small description box is opened underneath. The problem I'm having is that the box that appears is the same width as the movie box, whereas I want it to take up the full space of the row. See image for illustration.Ilustration of problem
here is the part of my code that has the problem. It is consisting of two react components and a css file
type here
import { useState } from 'react';
import FilmBild from './assets/filmBild.jpg';
import SingleMovieGridElement from "./SingleMovieGridElement.jsx";

function MovieGrid() {

    const [selectedMovieId, setSelectedMovieId] = useState(null);

    const handleMovieClick = (movieId) => {
        if (selectedMovieId === movieId) {
            setSelectedMovieId(null); // Om samma film klickas igen, stäng av beskrivningen
        } else {
            setSelectedMovieId(movieId);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row gx-4 gy-4"> {/* gx-4 ger horisontell space, gy-4 ger vertikal space */}

                <SingleMovieGridElement handleMovieClick={handleMovieClick} selectedMovieId={selectedMovieId} />
                <div className="card mt-2 movie-description">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}



{/*

*/}
export default MovieGrid;


import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom';
//import {useState} from "react";


function SingleMovieGridElement({handleMovieClick, selectedMovieId}) {

    //const [handleMovieClick, selectedMovieId] = useOutletContext()

    const movies = useLoaderData();
    console.log("filmer")
    console.log(movies)

    return(

        <>

        {movies.map((movie) => (
                <div key={movie.details.id} className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <div className="card">
                        <img
                            src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.details["poster_path"]}`}
                            className="card-img-top img-fluid"
                            alt={movie.details["original_title"]}
                            onClick={() => handleMovieClick(movie.details.id)} // Klicka för att visa beskrivningen
                        />
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title"
                                style={{ fontSize:'1rem' }}>
                                {movie.details["original_title"]}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {/* Shows description for the selcted movie */}
                    {selectedMovieId === movie.details.id && (
                        <div className="card mt-2 movie-description">
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <p>{movie.details["overview"]}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            ))}
    </>)
}

export default SingleMovieGridElement;

#root {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  height: 6em;
  padding: 1.5em;
  will-change: filter;
  transition: filter 300ms;
}
.logo:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #646cffaa);
}
.logo.react:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2em #61dafbaa);
}

@keyframes logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  a:nth-of-type(2) .logo {
    animation: logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.card {
  padding: 2em;
}

.read-the-docs {
  color: #888;
}


.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 350px; 
}

.card-img-top {
  max-height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover; 
}

.card-body {
  flex: 1; 
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.4; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  white-space: normal; 
  height: 50px;  
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.card-body p {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #666;
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  white-space: normal; 
  height: 70px; 
}



.movie-description {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 300px; 
  overflow-y: auto; 
}

.row {
  position: relative;
}




I have tried playing with setting the position of movie-description to absolute and left:0; and setting the position of .row to relative so that it fills the space. This kind of fixes the width part, it's a little off but not terrible. the problem however is that the rest of the movie boxes ends up on top of the description box. I believe that a large part of the problem is that the description box is contained by the size of the movie box in some sense and therefore it's so problematic. This is my first course in web programming som I'm very new to this. Any help is very much appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

From your question and provided snippet what i understood is that you have a grid layout with movie cards. Where each card can expand to show a description and the description should span the full width of the row.
Now the issue that you are occurring is that the description box is constrained by the width of the individual movie card and by using position: absolute causes overlap with other elements.
So, how to fix it right. I would suggest you to

Use a separate component for the description that spans the full row.
Move the description outside of the individual card component.
Implement a state to control which movie's description is shown.

Example snippet that also might work for you.
Update MovieGrid, SingleMovieGridElement & create a new component called MovieDescription
// MovieGrid.jsx
import { useState } from 'react';
import FilmBild from './assets/filmBild.jpg';
import SingleMovieGridElement from "./SingleMovieGridElement.jsx";
import MovieDescription from "./MovieDescription.jsx";

function MovieGrid() {
    const [selectedMovieId, setSelectedMovieId] = useState(null);
    const [selectedMovieDetails, setSelectedMovieDetails] = useState(null);

    const handleMovieClick = (movieId, movieDetails) => {
        if (selectedMovieId === movieId) {
            setSelectedMovieId(null);
            setSelectedMovieDetails(null);
        } else {
            setSelectedMovieId(movieId);
            setSelectedMovieDetails(movieDetails);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row gx-4 gy-4">
                <SingleMovieGridElement handleMovieClick={handleMovieClick} />
            </div>
            {selectedMovieDetails && (
                <MovieDescription movieDetails={selectedMovieDetails} />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default MovieGrid;


// SingleMovieGridElement.jsx:
import { useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom';

function SingleMovieGridElement({ handleMovieClick }) {
    const movies = useLoaderData();

    return (
        <>
            {movies.map((movie) => (
                <div key={movie.details.id} className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <div className="card">
                        <img
                            src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${movie.details["poster_path"]}`}
                            className="card-img-top img-fluid"
                            alt={movie.details["original_title"]}
                            onClick={() => handleMovieClick(movie.details.id, movie.details)}
                        />
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title" style={{ fontSize: '1rem' }}>
                                {movie.details["original_title"]}
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}

export default SingleMovieGridElement;

// MovieDescription.jsx
function MovieDescription({ movieDetails }) {
    return (
        <div className="col-12 mt-4 movie-description">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{movieDetails["original_title"]}</h5>
                    <p>{movieDetails["overview"]}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MovieDescription;

/* index.css */
/* ... existing styles ... */

.movie-description {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /* Changed from fixed height */
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Removed scroll */
}

.row {
    position: relative;
}



Thank you for answering. Your tips took me in the right direction
